Why don't professors seem to use learning strategies like spaced repetition and note-taking?
I've always been curious about the learning habits of professors and other academic experts. According to research, strategies like spaced repetition and active note-taking are among the most effective methods for retaining information and understanding complex topics. However, in my experience, I rarely see professors using these techniques.
For instance, many professors seem to learn new information without explicitly using spaced repetition systems or even taking detailed notes. They often appear to rely on their deep understanding and expertise in the field to retain and recall information.
So I wanted to ask:

Do professors use these strategies in a way that isn't visible to students?
How do professors deal with the potential forgetting of information over time without using spaced repetition?
What is the learning strategy that professors use


There is no "learning strategy that professors use" in the same way there isn't a "productivity hack that top managers use", independently of what various books or blogs are trying to peddle to you.

Why do you assume professors don't take notes?

Reading with the goal of solving a research problem is pretty effective (proportional to how directly the reading helps solves that problem).

I suggest you should specify the exact situations you are referring to. E.g., a professor who is taking a new course for professional development or a professor who is participating in a meeting etc. Otherwise, the question sounds ambiguous to me, because it is not a common situation to see a professor learning something new out there in the wild.

Is this question asking why professors don't use spaced repetition and active note-taking for their learning or why they don't use spaced repetition and active note-taking for the work they assign their students?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_pyramid

There is one learning strategy that is used by "advanced learners" (such as professors) which is also relevant. "Doing it your own way". Whether it is by re-doing a calculation in your own notation or writing your own program or repeating an experiment. Once you have enough "stored information", it is useful to fit things you are learning with what you already know and DIYOW is a good way to "place" new knowledge in your personal store.

These people are experienced and probably developed their own way of doing things which you not necessarily imitate.

"However, in my experience, I rarely see professors using these techniques." I'm really curious what you mean by that. Both my fellow postdocs and the professors I work with "learn" in private, if there were someone in my office while I tried to grok something on my own I would probably kick them right out. What relevance does it have what you see these people doing?

During the process of, say writing a paper, you have to understand the material and related works to a great degree and describe them in written words throughout the course of weeks, which involves actively thinking about the topic all day long. That is far far more repetitions than a student typically does for any test.

These aren't the only advanced learning techniques. If I read a paper then try to use their methods in my own research, that cements it in my mind like nothing else. Likewise, if I have to turn around teach it, the content will be with me until I'm senile (which is also a form of spaced repetition). If you've taught, you know the sad secret that the person learning the most in the class is the teacher.

Anecdotal evidence has it that professors are not the best learners ;-).

Professors, by the point in their career that you are interacting with them as a student, don't need to spend their days memorizing information. Most people who are at that level in academia are interested in generating new knowledge. Most likely, they already have a wealth of information at their fingertips as a result of years of schooling and then work/research in their field. You usually don't forget the things you use every day (and if you do, were they really that important to begin with?).
When someone at that stage wants to learn something new, it is usually coming from academic literature. The point is not to memorize but to understand what another scientist has done, usually to advance one's own research. Active note taking is helpful here - I take notes when I read papers I feel are particularly important - but it isn't always necessary. Besides, you can always pull up that paper again if you need to clarify something. The goal is not memorization or even long-term retention.
Spaced repetition and active note taking are excellent ways to memorize information. Hopefully you also gain a good understanding in the process, but the focus of these strategies (at least in practice) is really retention of discrete facts. This is very useful for students. As a student, you are expected to remember a set amount of pre-ordained info for a test. On top of that, your fund of knowledge is still small, so it is helpful to commit things to memory. Once you are out of school, the amount of information that you legitimately need to memorize, let alone regurgitate on command, is effectively 0. Obviously we can imagine situations where spaced repetition could still be useful (learning a new language for example), but I have to imagine that in day-to-day life, absolutely noone is going to do Anki flashcards for fun.
The point I'm trying to make is that you are thinking about this from the perspective of a student. You are in the artificial confines of the university system. Spaced repetition is a very useful tool for learning large volumes of information in a reliable and relatively quick way (and theoretically maintaining it over time). But it really isn't super beneficial for someone who is not constrained by that system i.e., does not have tests to take. Plus, spaced repetition is boring an can quickly become overwhelming. You should not expect to do that (at least consciously) for the rest of your life.

I think overall memorization is probably utilized too often by students, as well, and students who rely too much on memorization techniques struggle specifically when they get to research levels in academia if they haven't learned other ways to learn and process information.

What I have found particularly useful (outside academics, granted) is the ability to remember where I found a connection or piece of information. It often seems I have good recall of details, when in fact I just often know where to find them (or search my personal wiki for notes that lead me to them, which amounts to the same thing).

@BryanKrause: That's what I used to think, but having interacted with more students, I think by and large they are actually optimizing for themselves.  The other ways we have to learn and process information may be more effective, but they are also more cognitively demanding, and many students simply lack sufficient working memory (or quick enough non-sequential retrieval from short term non-working memory) for our strategies to work for them.  Memorization is the best they can do.

I agree with @AlexanderWoo's comment, and I think that some/many students (consciously or not) place a limit on the amount of effort and mental commitment to some of the things they study. Apparently memorization is (subliminally?) interpreted as a minimizing/optimizing strategy? :)

@AlexanderWoo I'm not sure it's that it's less effort (I always find that sort of thing more effort), but that we learn information by using it for really purposes.  However much we try,  that just isn't the same for students - they are not avidly using information and concepts professionally on a day to day basis.

I think the other answers are a bit to quick to dismiss requirements for learning throughout an academic career. I am always learning new things, whether this is learning about new advances in my field, learning how to use new techniques (for example, the syntax of a new domain specific package), or even the details of a whole new fields or sub field that has become newly relevant to my research. While a lot of this is understanding and conceptual learning, rather than factual memorisation, there are still facts to learn, such as the syntax above, or for example,  the list of genes affected by some newly discovered process. Also understanding of concepts benefits from repetition.
So why don't you see professors using formal learning techniques? Well, in fact, many of them ARE implicitly using these techniques.  Firstly plenty of professors take notes in seminars, at conferences and when they read papers. Few ever look at these notes again, but the very act of making them helps with processing.
Secondly, spaced repetition. I would guess that the learning technique of spaced repetition was initially conceptualised to imitate the way a professional gains and uses knowledge. If I look something up and just use it once, then it is unlikely I will retain it. But no matter. If it was something I only needed once, then it seems it was expedient not to memorise it.  On the other hand, if I find myself repeatedly using the same piece of information, every time I look it up is a instance of spaced repetition. Those things that are frequently useful will eventually find their way into my brain. Similarly if I keep seeing seminars talking about the same list of genes involved in a process, next time I see that gene name, I'm far more likely to connect it to that process than if I'd only seen one seminar.

"Few ever look at these notes again, but the very making them helps with processing." yep, when learning to program it is much better to type things for yourself than cut and paste for exactly that reason.

@DikranMarsupial - The act of writing notes is indeed a very powerful tool. Multiple studies show using pen and paper is better than the alternatives. When I was in school there were no other alternatives, but I rapidly figured out that, for me, reviewing what I had written didn't help me study later at all.

Yes, I suppose you can say that taking notes is a learning strategy or technique. But I don't think you can say the same of repeatedly needing the same piece of information or repeatedly encountering the same list of genes. These are just things that happen.

@toby544 my point is not that these are learning techniques,  but that these learning techniques are simulations of such "things that happen" in situations  where they don't.

Yes, I'd second @IanSudbery's comment that these "learning strategies" are rather caricatured/formalized versions of what people actually do... for novices who do not have a visceral sense of the more sophisticated process.

These sound like methods for students who need to understand and remember things for exams.
Professors don't need to take exams, and they are much more practiced at identifying and remembering the things that are useful to them when they watch a presentation or read a publication. They also know their own ways of understanding and remembering things much better than students do, so they have their own methods that they use when necessary.
Answers to your bullets:

No.
They just write them down. No special technique is necessary. They are not studying for exams.
None, or they each have their own ways.


This is actually a pretty interesting question!
Taking myself as an example, I feel like generally I just read deeply (or listen) and make sure I understand something the first time, and it generally sticks.
I feel like I probably do have a somewhat better memory than the average person in the general population; e.g., usually have a sense-memory for what the page looked like where I saw a certain piece of information.
I realized around the end of my master's degree that I was actually better off in a lecture session not taking notes, and instead to just focus on actively listening to the lecturer. (These were all classes where we had a textbook I could use as added support outside of class.) When that dawned on me, I was kind of kicking myself for all the tremendous effort I'd previously put in to trying to maintain lecture notes.
And (as a math person) I've actually come to disagree with the popular opinion that you need to do lots of practice to get math. It was my partner who first said something like, "you either understand the principle or you don't, doing a bunch of repeated practice doesn't make a big difference". It took me a while to embrace that, but I do think it's my truth. The point of mathematics are the big-picture relationships, and if you can just fully grok those statements, the exercises are kind of tangential and beside the point.
All this adds extra impetus to being very skeptical of the advice that comes from education researchers, as in general they're pretty much the opposite of my own experience. Is the general student just very different from myself and other professors (even at the same stage of development)? Seems likely. Arguably it also reflects the social evolution to try and (pretend?) get a very large percent of the population through advanced education, and so need an increased system of hand-holding to get that to happen (compare current textbooks to those a century ago).

You don't need lots of practice to get math.  You need lots of practice to learn to do a particular kind of math problem without having gotten the math.

You might also need lots of practice to be able to solve those particular kinds of maths problems fast enough for exam conditions. I expect that student ability being measured by exam performance accounts for the biggest differences between education researchers and your own experience.

"They often appear to rely on their deep understanding and expertise in the field to retain and recall information."
I think this is exactly it (and it is a matter of selection bias, it is difficult to get to be a prof without a deep understanding of your subject area).
Remembering unconnected facts is really hard.  However if the new fact is related to things you already know and understand then they are much easier to remember as they become part of your internal cognitive model of the subject.  The difference between knowledge and understanding is (IMHO) largely about forming connections between related things that you know.  It takes time to build understanding, so students tend to need special techniques to remember things long enough to join them together with something else.  If your brain is already full of connected things, there is usually something immediately available to hang the new fact on.
However, the opposite may also be true.  If your brain is already full of connected knowledge forming a well established cognitive model, then it can be very difficult to insert a new fact (c.f. reception for special relativity, Kuhn's idea of commensurability) that is fundamentally inconsistent with that model.  This may make students (or early career researchers) better equipped to deal with paradigm shifts.

Think of the following analogy:
When you speak a language, you do not spend time repeating vocabulary or practicing writing sentences. You speak and write, as you go.
Of course, literature-level writers may spend a lot of time refining their words, but that's a different matter.
The level of a prof on their topic can be compared to the level of a native speaker of a language. And sometimes to a writer that needs to fine-tune (sometimes obsessively) how they use the language. But they do not need to rehearse vocabulary and grammar.

First, I don't think you can have the slightest idea what learning techniques professors use. OK, if you are particularly close to a professor you might ask them about it, but professors learn outside of your sight, either sitting in their offices, or at home, or other places. Maybe some do use these methods, but you can't tell.
Second, different people learn differently. By the time a person is a professor, they have figured out how they learn. After all, they've had 12 years of elementary school, four of college, then usually several years of grad school and then more in their careers. (Numbers will vary slightly by country). And professors are people who are really good at this type of learning (they make stink at other forms!  John von Neumann was a terrible driver.)
Third, spaced repetition is good for learning facts and simple routines. Professors don't do much of this kind of learning, at least, not in their professional lives. (I use spaced repetition via Chessable to try to improve my chess game).
Fourth, I'd be willing to bet that many professors do take notes. But the nature of those notes varies by individual (I was always on the low end) and by what they are learning. Are you doing research for an article or book? LOTS of notes. Are you sitting in a seminar with other experts? Probably very few notes.

"First, I don't think you can have the slightest idea what learning techniques professors use."
Yes, that's probably why they came onto the Academia Stack Exchange and asked "What is the learning strategy professors use?"

@WhatTheDuck Well, OP does say "many professors seem to learn new information without explicitly using spaced repetition systems or even taking detailed notes" which implies they think they have an idea.

@Azor Ahai I don't know that that necessarily implies that they think they have an idea, merely that they don't see professors using systems that OP is familiar with - they're using the notetaking as a reference point for what they ARE familiar with. So then they asked what systems professors are using. I think the first paragraph of this answer is unnecessarily snarky and borderline rude for no reason - OP came here to learn something, they don't need to be denigrated for it.

@WhatTheDuck Frankly I think both the OQ and Peter's answer come across as a little snarky; the OQ toward professors.

@WhatTheDuck I disagree with the premise of this comment. This question clearly lacked any research done before asking and is far too vague for any conclusive answer. Are we just going to encourage users to not put any effort unto themselves to answer their questions, even though we KNOW the answer is obvious because it cannot be answered concretely?

@AzorAhai-him- I personally don't find any snark whatsoever in the OP's question. It reads as someone who just genuinely doesn't understand how their professors appear to know so much.

@Shidouuu ...Okay? What research should OP have done? I googled "how do professors learn things" to see what OP might have found, and the results aren't helpful. I really don't get this attitude where, because the answer is obvious to you, OP should be denigrated for asking the question.

@WhatTheDuck How about asking the professors that are teaching them, or any professors at all? "'Hello professor X, I am curious about how professors learn, and it as occured to me that few if any use spaced repetition. Why is this, and why don't you?' 'Oh, I don't use spaced repetition because my field requires to understand xyz...,' 'I do use spaced repetition! Just not for the clases I teach.'" This would give OP a far better response than just asking SE a general question. The type of answer is obvious because obviously not all professors learn the same way.

@Shidouuu ...So OP shouldn't ask this question on a website (whose user base includes a bunch of professors that actually respond to questions) and should instead try cold-emailing a bunch of professors at their institution, who, as we all know, are famously responsive and happy to read and then answer long-form emails from students.  in case that was not apparent.
What exactly do you think this website is for, if you think questions like this have no place here?

To answer your question first:

Do professors use these strategies in a way that isn't visible to
students? -

YES, When I'm assigned to teach a new class I start with reading the text book and taking notes (in the form of PowerPoint slides).  As I teach I make adjustments in real time and from one class to the next and from semester to semester.

How do professors deal with the potential forgetting of
information over time without using spaced repetition?

For me it's the willingness to accept looking stupid in front of people that may expect me to remember. For example, I took it upon myself to remember my students names and used repetition (daily role call) to remember them, in about 4 weeks I would remember almost all 100 or so my students (this was precovid). Of course when the next semester started I would soon forget my past students to make space for my new students. Actually, it was more like 5 years, where I would bump into students and not know who they were.

What is the learning strategy that professors use?

I would say it's the same as with everyone. For new material, repetition and note taking. I don't know the proper terms used to describe addition to an existing knowledge base other than saying there are terms like confirmation bias, recency effects, and small sample bias.

To add context, my dissertation was based on an alternative explanation to a paper I read that claimed experts performing a task with computer software were no different than novices. My alternative explanation was that was not surprising in that I would expect anyone thrown into a new situation (using a computer software to do a task) to perform like a novice. For the most part my disseration was devising a way to test my alternative explanation.
In summary, professors are falling back on tried strategies (repetition and note taking) when put into new situations. But not everything a professor does falls into that situation.

Yes, as a professor, I constantly take notes on what I'm reading about. I even try to impart good note-taking skills to my students by telling them about my note-taking techniques. It seems like the OP just hasn't met every professor out there yet.

Everyone has different innate abilities that result in differences in learning styles. In my own experience, I learn more effectively by repeated use of skills. Once I have practiced something sufficiently I am able to produce effectively and build new skills. This was explained to me well into my career, past the erosion of my "golden boy" image during the descent to the premature end of a promising career. If I had known how to learn as a teenager, there would have been much broader horizons open to me. My son is currently riding his  own personal abilities far more successfully than I did.

People - not just professors - who have a deep understanding of a field can often learn things much more easily than someone new to the subject. They can relate the new concept(s) to things they already know, and fill in details with a little thought.
They don't have to learn huge lists of facts, because they already know them, or can deduce them quickly and easily. That's easier and more satisfying than recalling memorised information. Just beware of people who think they have such expertise for everything.
